# Unable to run php localhost on Yosemite

Tags: php, localhost, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run a php script from my localhost on Mac mavericks. But the server doesn't recognize my user. This is my setup:

```
/etc/apache2/users/filipefr.conf

<Directory "/Users/filipefr/Sites/">
    AddLanguage en .en
    LanguagePriority en fr de
    ForceLanguagePriority Fallback
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

localserver is running, not reconizing my file/user

This is the file I'm trying to run:

```
 <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

on this localserver url:

```
http://192.168.0.12/filipefr/info.php
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognizing" ?

Comment: the server returns this message: The requested URL /filipefr/info.php was not found on this server.

Comment: have you checked that it exists there?

Comment: Have you tried using 'localhost' instead of '192.168.0.12' in the url?